# HTML Video Tag controls missing in portrait and landscape mode but ok when not in any of the following mode

Tags: javascript, android, html, video, html5-video

With the following code, a simple webpage is created with a video. However, when i change to portrait or landscape mode, the controls will be missing? Why is it like that and what can I do to resolve it?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
    <body> 

    <video width="400" controls>
      <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>

    <p>
    Video courtesy of 
    <a href="https://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.
    </p>

    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: It is likely caused by css, do you have a live demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing my video tag inside the div with data-tap-disable = true seems to work for me. It seems to be a problem with Ionic 1. And adding the following code will help my video controls to appear in android as well as web.

```
<div data-tap-disabled="true">
    <video>
    </video>
    </div>
```